# error: cannot convert Elem to Elem* for argument 1 to void addHead(Elem*, Elem*)

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, linked-list

I am compiling my code with g++ -g and I am getting the error message in the title.

The error is related to a function I have made, it's signature being:

```
void addHead( Elem *&start , Elem *newStart );
```

and I am passing this function these two variables:

```
Elem * head;    
Elem * tempEl;
```

so that it looks like this:

```
addHead( *head , *tempEl );
```

The actual function is:

```
void addHead( Elem start , Elem newStart )
{
Elem listItem;

listItem = newStart;
*listItem.next = start;
start = listItem;
}
```

It pre-pends the second argument to the the beginning of a linked-list starting at the first argument.

I have been pulling my hair out with this one. No matter what I do I keep getting this error!

```
cannot convert Elem to Elem* for argument 1 to void addHead(Elem*, Elem*)
```

Edit: Forgot this error is in there too:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type Elem*& from expression of type Elem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's being pretty specific: You're passing an `Elem`, but it takes an `Elem*`. In particular, `head` is of type `Elem*`, but you are passing `*head`: of type `Elem`.

Also, your definition signature doesn't match your definition, so even when you fix the call, you will get a linker error when it can't find `addHead(Elem*, Elem*)`. Definitions must *exactly* their signatures (more correctly, declarations). Of course, neither of these changes will fix the actual implementation of `addHead()`, but that's *your* homework :)